# XCode autocomplete not work in #ifdef code block

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am woking with a application that use this kind of block:

```
#ifdef xxx
   codes go here 
#endif
```

I dont know that why xcode's auto complete doesn't works inside in code blocks.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may don't work because your code at this place doesn't run for current settings (xxx is undefined)